# Does anti spam software block IP addresses of large smtp providers?

Tags: email, smtp, spam

Does anti spam software routinely block IP addresses of large smtp providers such as Mailchimp or SalesHandy?

Comment: This question is extremely vague.  Which anti-spam software?

Comment: @user2752635 any of them.

Comment: `Does anti spam software routinely block IP addresses of large smtp providers such as Mailchimp or SalesHandy?` - Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Interpreting your question literally and naively: yes, I'm sure there is at least one spam filter which will block ip addresses based on naive metrics.

I can't imagine how this information will be helpful to you but without further information on what you want to achieve I can't provide more information.